# Show friends on application

Tags: facebook, facepile

I have a FB app. I need to have a functionality similar to which is present on Washington post reader that shows friends on the app.

Is it FB facepile? If so, then how have they implemented to show more than 4 friends with a button? Have they implemented it server side ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FQL to retrieve friends using the same app.
Simply use the query below and you should be able to get frineds' uid, name and is_app_user.
*is_app_user* indicates if a given user is using your app or not.

> select uid, name, is_app_user from user where uid in (select uid2 from
>   friend where uid1=me()) and is_app_user=1

Comment: Sorry if I havent made my query clear.This is not what I want. I am aware of this , but I just wanted to know if I can show my friends in Washington Post style , using FB Facepile?

Comment: I guess, although the html class name is "facepile", they are not using FB Facepile. I'm not sure if they implemented this on server side or client side, though. If you want to use facepile, you can still customize the size of the icons and the open graph action for grouping.